# loop on Multiple array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am confused about how to `iterate` on `multiple values`.

for example : `values.categories[0].num[0].entry[0].label;`

Do I need to write three `for` loops in order to iterate through categories, num and entry.

Because `categories[0]` will always identify the `1st position`, but am looking for generic `categories[i]`.

Can you please help me out whether to write three for loops or better option is there to achieve.?

This is what I have tried:

```
var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                var abc = categories[i].num;
                for (var j = 0; j < abc.length; j++){
                    var def = num[i].entry;
                }
                for(var k = 0; k < def.length; k++){
                    var ghi = entry[i].label;
                    result.push(ghi)
                    console.log(result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: any code what should appreciated

Comment: When you have `n` dimensions you have to write `n` nested for loops or equivalent to reach all elements.

Comment: You can use a recursive function if the depth is unknown.

Comment: JS has a very shallow stack though.

Comment: you're nowhere using the loop variables j & k. If that is what you need, i.e only access using i values, then there is no need for the extra two loops.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the each function of jquery.

```
$.each(categories, function(ci, num) {

    // This set the index of the array in ci and the value in num = categories[ci]

    $.each(num, function(ni, entry) {

        // etc ... 

    });

});
```

if you want it to stop the iteration you can return false inside the callback function.